# How to call same query multiple times using apollo client in react js on first mount

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I need to call the query on status change when component mounted.
Let's say I have 5 status in array and I'm looping that array.

The expected output should be: that query must be called 5 times.

But the problem is only one time query was called for the status which is at last position in an array.

```
const loadedStatus = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

const [listSomeData] = useLazyQuery(LIST_SOME_DATA, {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
    });

const listSomeDataHandler = async (statusId, pagination = {}, filters = {}) => {
        await listSomeData({
            variables: {
                statusId,
                page: pagination?.page,
                pageSize: pagination?.pageSize,
                ...filters
            }
        });
    };

useEffect(async () => {
        loadedStatus &&
            Promise.all(
                loadedStatus.map(status => {
                    listSomeDataHandler(
                        status.id, 
                        { page: 0, pageSize: 10 }, 
                        filters
                     );
                })
            );
    },[loadedStatus]);
```

Comment: Could you share some code? What you have done since now?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I have added some code. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

async in `useEffect` should be considered an antipattern ([here](https://dev.to/danialdezfouli/what-s-wrong-with-the-async-function-in-useeffect-4jne) an explanation) and you should get a warning like `Warning: An Effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.`.
Not only but your `useEffect` has a missing dependency: `listSomeDataHandler`.

In this case, much better call an async function inside the `useEffect` (and move `listSomeDataHandler` inside `useEffect`). So your code becomes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const listSomeDataHandler = async (status) => {
      await listSomeData(status);
    };

    (async () => {
      Promise.all(
        loadedStatus.map((status) => {
          return listSomeDataHandler(status);
        })
      );
    })();
  }, [loadedStatus]);
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-j9wrp?file=/src/index.js) I made a codesandbox example and, as you can see, `listSomeDataHandler` will be called 5 times.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Everything works fine but when you implement apollo client query inside  handler, only one time that query is being called. Here  listSomeData is a graphql client query.